# Why is the template specialization function not being accessed

Tags: c++, templates

**Problem Description**

In the following code we have 2 classes `A` and `B` where`B` inherits from `A`. We also have 2 template functions `test(T &t)` and `test(A &a)`.  The output of the code is "A1".

Why the `test(A &a)` function isn't being used in this example?

---

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>
class A {};
class B: public A {};

template<typename T>
void test(T &t){std::cout <<"A1";}
template<>
void test(A& a){std::cout <<"A2";}

// If we put test(A& a) before test(T &t) we get the compilation error
// 'test' is not a template function

int main() {
    A *a = new B();
    test(a);
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use `void test(A*& a){std::cout <<"A2";}` as `A *` (from `A *a = new B();` ) is not an `A`.  So the specialisation does not match and the more general template does.

Comment: @RichardCritten if I do as you typed. Why would the compiler then output "A2" is there a preference on picking either A1 or A2?

Comment: Exact match `a` is an lvalue pointer to `A` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/438r49jbE  Whereas `T` need to be deduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to pass a value of type `A*` to a function accepting `A&`. These are incompatible types, a pointer is not a reference. So the specialization `test(A&)` isn't considered, and the main template is used with `T` deduced as `A*`.

If we change the call `test(a)` to `test(*a)`, then the program will print `A2`.

```
#include <iostream>
class A {};
class B: public A {};

template<typename T>
void test(T &t){std::cout <<"A1";}
template<>
void test(A& a){std::cout <<"A2";}

// If we put test(A& a) before test(T &t) we get the compilation error
// 'test' is not a template function

int main() {
    A *a = new B();
    test(*a);              // <==== Here
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nlV8LVRPpSPmaOu0))